# converting 1x1 matrix to a variable

Tags: matlab, csv

I read the data from the `csv` which contains two columns `id` which `text/string` and the `cancer` which is `1/0`. please see the code be

```
M = readtable('data.csv');
```

I try to access the very first value using

```
row= M(n,1); //It's from the ID column which is text
```

But it comes in the form of a `1x1`matrix, and I am unable to put it in a single variable. 
for example I want after the above line works `row` should contain a string in it like. `row = 'patientID'`. Now is there anyway to convert it into a single value?

Comment: Use `row = M{n,1}`.  Note the curly braces.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Thank, It solved my problem, please tell me how I can I mark your question as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row = M{n,1}`. Note the curly braces.

The curly braces say "get the contents of the table", as opposed to the circular brackets you had been using which say "get me a portion of the table, as a table".